# Insert class when child container contains certain text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a specific case here where I need to add a third container after the second container if certain text matches the first child container.

So:

```
<div class="ans_value">
<b class="ans_value_title">123</b>
<span class="ans_value_text>abc</span>
</div>
```

becomes below if ans_value_title contains 123:

```
<div class="ans_value">
<b class="ans_value_title">123:</b>
<span class="ans_value_text>abc</span>
<div class="ans_value_new></div>
</div>
```

Here's the code I tried but didn't work:

```
if ($('div.ans_value > b.ans_value_title:contains("123:")').length > 0) {
    $(".ans_value_new").addClass("thisClass");
}
```

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Can use `filter()` or an `each` loop to make it instance specific

```js
$('.ans_value_title').filter(function(){
   return $(this).text().trim() === '123'
}).parent().append('<div class="ans_value_new">New div</div>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ans_value">
  <b class="ans_value_title">123</b>
  <span class="ans_value_text">abc</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
$('.ans_value').children().eq(0).text()=='123'&&//check the first children's value
$('.ans_value').append('<div class="ans_value_new></div>')//inject dom at end
```